# How to substitute a part of the line in XML with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, replace, substitution

I have following XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mets:mets xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/">
 <mets:fileSec>
    <mets:fileGrp ID="rep1" ADMID="rep1-amd">
      <mets:file ID="fid1-1" ADMID="fid1-1-amd">
        <mets:FLocat xmlns:xlin="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" LOCTYPE="URL" xlin:href="/exlibris1/transfer/lza-tib/submission.tib/ingest/GBV631313192/content/streams/MASTER/Prandtl_4.pdf"/>

      </mets:file>
    </mets:fileGrp>
    <mets:fileGrp ID="rep2" ADMID="rep2-amd">
      <mets:file ID="fid1-2" ADMID="fid1-2-amd">
        <mets:FLocat xmlns:xlin="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" LOCTYPE="URL" xlin:href="/exlibris1/transfer/lza-tib/submission.tib/ingest/GBV631313192/content/streams/DERIVATIVE_COPY/631313192.pdf"/>
      </mets:file>
    </mets:fileGrp>
  </mets:fileSec>
</mets:mets>
```

For every mets:FLocat I want to do the following change:

now:
 `<mets:FLocat xmlns:xlin="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" LOCTYPE="URL" xlin:href="/exlibris1/transfer/lza-tib/submission.tib/ingest/GBV631313192/content/streams/MASTER/Prandtl_4.pdf"/>`

has to be: `<mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlin:href="file://MASTER/Prandtl_4.pdf" xmlns:xlin="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>`

So we delete `/exlibris1/transfer/lza-tib/submission.tib/ingest/GBV631313192/content/streams` and instead of  it add  `file://`

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>


 <xsl:for-each select="/mets:mets/mets:filesec/mets:fileGrp/mets:file/mets:Flocat"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="xlin:href"/>
</xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm very new to XSLT and I don't know how to refer to the line which I have to change. Maybe some ideas?

Comment: If you want to change an attribute value then write a template for the attribute and implement that change. Are you really restricted to XSLT `version="1.0"` or why have you used that version in your XSLT code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider to use XSLT 3 (as supported by Saxon 9.8 or Altova XMLSpy 2017 or 2018) and then it is as easy as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/"
    xmlns:xlin="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="mets:FLocat/@xlin:href">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="'file://' || replace(., '^/exlibris1/transfer/lza-tib/submission.tib/ingest/GBV631313192/content/streams', '')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kn

For XSLT 2 you would need to spell out the identity transformation as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/"
    xmlns:xlin="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mets:FLocat/@xlin:href">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="concat('file://', replace(., '^/exlibris1/transfer/lza-tib/submission.tib/ingest/GBV631313192/content/streams', ''))"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kn/2

With XSLT 1 there is no general string replacement but as you want to use the end of the attribute value after a certain string you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/"
    xmlns:xlin="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mets xlin"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mets:FLocat/@xlin:href">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('file://', substring-after(., '/exlibris1/transfer/lza-tib/submission.tib/ingest/GBV631313192/content/streams'))"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kn/3

Comment: What I forgot to explain is that instead of GBV631313192 different digits could occur and the number of digits isn't always constant. So maybe it should be regular expression there

Comment: Well, the XSLT 2 and 3 solutions already use a regular expression with the `replace` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace, so adapt that based on your needs e.g. `replace(., '^/exlibris1/transfer/lza-tib/submission.tib/ingest/GBV[0-9]+/content/streams', '')`. Pure XSLT/XPath 1 has no regular expression support so you would first need to find out whether your choosen XSLT processor supports some extension function or extension mechanism (e.g. calling into Java or Javascript or .NET)  to use regular expressions.

Comment: Is it possible to substitute GBV631313192 through the wildcard such as .* in xslt 1.0 ?

Comment: No, not in pure XSLT/XPath 1.0. You can find its functions at https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/ by the way. xsltproc might support extensions, check its documentation.